# PayPal - Check tickets still available before sending the money

Tags: php, paypal, authorization, stock

I'm working on an online ticket distribution system.
The system checks if the tickets are available before the user attempts to pay, however, it might happen that the tickets run out while the user is paying.
I want to make it so that when the user actually completes the payment on paypal, if the tickets have ran out it cancels the payment and warns the user.

I'm not asking for a complete tutorial, but I'm asking about what payment method I should use (Adaptive Payments, Express Checkout) and what parts of the API I should refer to. I'm using the classic API.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any of PayPal's payment products. The standard thing to do when selling limited quantity goods, or other goods which have fullfillment costs/delays/challenges, is to collect a payment authorization from the buyer (so use PAYMENTACTION=AUTHORIZATION), then allocate/reserve/sell the goods to that particular buyer, then capture the funds.

Personally I recommend Express Checkout over Adaptive Payments, although both products handle this flow just fine. Taking EC as the example you would check ticket availability, do SetEC, redirect the user to PayPal for login, call GetEC, (optionally here you can again check avalability), and call DoEC with paymentaction=authorization. Now you are guaranteed to be able to get the funds because you have reserved them from the buyer. Reserve/sell the tickets to the buyer. When that succeeds, call DoCapture to collect on the authorization. If the tickets vanished in the few seconds between DoEC and your reserving them (or some other fulfillment issue happens on your end), you call DoVoid to void the authorization and release the hold on the funds (although if your code explodes and fails to void the auth, it will expire in a few days anyway so impact to the buyer should be minimal).

Comment: I'm looking to do this without reserving tickets, yet. I'm supposed to finish the thing by tomorrow. I'm trying a method by using EC for now, I'll let you know. Thanks for suggesting me to use EC, it seems a bit better. Though, had a bit of an issue converting the curl response to an array, as it's not json, but I nailed that down.

Comment: That's the point: you don't have to reserve the tickets if you reserve the funds instead (via an auth). Reread the answer: I wrote "reserve/sell the tickets to the buyer" just to indicate what whatever you consider to be your fullfillment action, do it at that time.